# Com Error in Blip TV App for Optimum V Phone

Tags: applications, non-market, android-sdk, system-error

Good afternoon, I am attempting to get the Android Blip application working for my phone, as of this moment it only works for the Samsung Viberant and I currently do not have that phone.  Now though the power of [the Internet](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=806957) I managed to locate the apk and was able to get it installed to my phone, however whenever I attempt to run the device I get this error:

> The application blip.tv
>   (process com.blipnetworks.android.blipdroid) has
>   stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again.

I took a look into the apk to see if I could find the error via an SDK to give me a better idea of what this could lead to, however in my attempts of debugging and searching I was unable to determine what the issue is for this device.  Any assistance would be great since the ARM 6 chip isn't supported in flash and this would be the only means of me viewing videos from that site.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Talk to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are if it's only supported on the Samsung Vibrant there's a good reason why.  Until Blip is released for your phone model or someone manages to modify the app for other phones you're likely out of luck.